# Override write concern on an individual operation or query in project that uses spring data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am working spring boot project that uses spring data as an abstraction to access the database[MongoDB]. I want to change the write concern only for two specific operations.

Below is the entity and repository class that I use to access the Mongo DB collection:

- Entity

```
@Document(collection = "tests")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Test {
    
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String category;
   

}
```

- Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends BaseMongoRepository<Test> {
    ...

    @DeleteQuery(value="{'id':?0}, { writeConcern: { w : '2', wtimeout : 1000 }, delete=true")
    void safeDeleteByTestId(String id,String name);

    default void updateNameForAll(String category) {
        final Query query = query(where("category").is(category);
        final Update update = Update.update("name", name);
        getMongoOperations().updateMulti(query, updategetMetadata().getCollectionName());
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I modify the `updateNameForAll` method to increase the write concern only for this query? **I don't want to override write concern for the entire collection or database.**

Kind Regards,
Rando.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this issue:

I created a new interface named ETestRepository like below:

```
public interface ETestRepository {
    void safeUpdateNameForAll(String category);
}
```

Then I created a implementation of the interface:

```
public interface ETestRepositoryImpl implements  ETestRepository  {
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public void safeUpdateNameForAll(String accountId, String contextId, ChangeSetRowAction action) {
        mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.W2);
        final Query query = query(where("category").is(category);
        final Update update = Update.update("name", name);
        mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query,update, Test.class);
    }
}
```

In the end, I modified the `TestRepository` interface to extend the `ETestRepository` interface to include the `safeUpdateNameForAll` method.